# Iterate in generator

Tags: javascript

I have a few promises that I have to iterate with the generator. I created the `helper` function that prints the first promise but I have difficulties creating an iterator in a helper function to iterate all promises. I actually don't understand how `constant a`, `constant b`, and `constant c` can be iterated.

```js
const asyncTask1 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve('first resolved'), 1000)); 
const asyncTask2 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve('second resolved'), 1000)); 
const asyncTask3 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject('third rejected'), 1000)); 

async function helper(func) {
  let p = func().next().value
  let output = await p
  console.log(output)
}

helper(function* main() {
  try {
    const a = yield asyncTask1()
    console.log(a);
    const b = yield asyncTask2()
    console.log(b);
    const c = yield asyncTask3()
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('error happened', e);
  }
})
```

Output: `first resolved`

Should be:

`first resolved`

`second resolved`

`third rejected`

Comment: Can't you use async generators and [`for await...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) ? But regardless, your helper function only consumes the first value of the iterator. If you want to consume all, use `for(const p of func()) { ... }` to iterate over all values. But if you want to send values back into the generator you have to iterate "manually". It's not clear what `console.log(a);` etc should produce.

Comment: Generators halt on yield statements until they are called again. In order to get all three yield values, you need to call `.next()` on your generator three times. Of course it is simpler to do this with a loop, as Felix has already mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the generator only once using `.next()` only once so the function would yield only once. Also, when you can `func()` you are creating a new generator every time. Your try catch block is in generator inside which is yield, so it won't catch the error since yield would not throw an error. Finally, third task will not be a success, it will throw an error as it is rejected.

I will do it as below -

```js
const asyncTask1 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve('first resolved'), 1000));
const asyncTask2 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve('second resolved'), 1000));
const asyncTask3 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject('third rejected'), 1000));


async function execute() {
  try {
    const iterator = generator();
    let p = iterator.next().value;
    let output = await p;
    console.log(output);
    let q = iterator.next().value;
    let output1 = await q;
    console.log(output1);
    let r = iterator.next().value;
    let output2 = await r;
    console.log(output3);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('error happened', e);
  }
}

const generator = function* generator() {
  yield asyncTask1();
  yield asyncTask2();
  yield asyncTask3();
}

execute();
```

Referring to [@Felix Kling's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) comment, a more elegant way to do this would be -

```js
const asyncTask1 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve('first resolved'), 1000));
const asyncTask2 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve('second resolved'), 1000));
const asyncTask3 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject('third rejected'), 1000));


async function execute() {
  const iterator = generator();
  for await (const task of iterator) {
    try {
      let output = await task();
      console.log(output);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('error happened', e);
    }
  }
}

const generator = function* generator() {
  yield*[asyncTask1, asyncTask2, asyncTask3];
}

execute();
```